# How does rust searches for crates?

Tags: rust, termux

I am using termux and trying to compile a hello world in rust, of course it can't find std nor core, I want to know what is going on, it is quite opaque, which files are missing exactly, is it these?

```
$ ls $PREFIX/lib/rustlib/aarch64-linux-android/lib
libcstr-38cc1a700499a2b7.so            libicu_provider_macros-a70f76f425f67b0d.so  libserde_derive-221e8f38918486bf.so             libyoke_derive-91760fdd8460cca3.so
libdarling_macro-7b8000f62e2c15d5.so   libproc_macro_hack-0334bb6f224f7962.so      libthiserror_core_impl-f2c52c21a354b6ff.so      libzerofrom_derive-d617e7f86f6504a7.so
libderive_more-71b2ecc6e76493ab.so     librustc_driver-78f3b3010e7a7c26.so         libthiserror_impl-4af3faeadd561b3a.so           libzerovec_derive-508bcf32bf5cbb5e.so
libderive_setters-c8a70d2499d48f8a.so  librustc_fluent_macro-e6aa0ea268e4ad8f.so   libtracing_attributes-a629cf96ffb0f7a4.so
libdisplaydoc-dfd622a9e81bc289.so      librustc_macros-377d0e078de2eede.so         libunic_langid_macros_impl-bb5454d0d0ed57d6.so
```

they are not on /lib/rustlib but on $PREFIX/lib/rustlib, is that the problem?, how can I tell rust/cargo to use this? It's quite interesting as an academical excercise.

solutions on internet, are to simply use rustup, but rustup is not supported for android, but I also want to understand how rust actually searches for std and finds it, this is important, I tried using
`export RUSTFLAGS="-L $PREFIX/lib/rustlib/aarch64-linux-android/lib"`
it didn't seem to work either.
I also tried
`` rustc --sysroot $PREFIX/lib/rustlib/aarch64-linux-android src/main.rs error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std` `` 
which didn't seem to work either. Maybe I just need to compile std to android?

Answer (score 1):

you really can use `rustup` with a custom glibc built for `Termux` see [this](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/15851#issuecomment-1826439672) guide.

you will either use the `autopatchelf script` attached there for patching your elf files or patch your binaries with the project's official way of doing it, [here](https://github.com/termux-pacman/glibc-packages/wiki/About-glibc-runner-(grun)#configures-the-shell-to-make-glibc-binaries-work)

it's easy and it's working.